# How to prevent the particular child from event binding using Jquery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I am binding the scroll events to all my html elements. To get the all the elements i am using the below filter

```
var element = $(myelemt).parentsUntil("html").add($(window));
return  element
```

here element will return the body, window and all parents htmls tags.

For this html elements i am binding the events like below code:

```
element.on("scroll", function (e) {
$("#mywrapper3").html($("#mywrapper3").html() + "scrolling<br>");
}
```

Here i want to prevent particular child div element only from binding. How i can achive this?. 
For example in my page for one div element(element with mywrapper id in sample) i dont want to bind this scroll event.

Also, I have to filter the element like in first code only. So how to achieve this  instead of using stop propagation. Is there any way to do this.

I have prepared the one jsfiddle.Please get the link below
https://jsfiddle.net/khkcjb6o/
Thanks for any help

Comment: e.stopPropagation

Comment: thanks but i need a other solution instead of  stoppropagation

Comment: Why would you need everything but one element registered on scroll event? If you scroll anytime on that page, everything fires anyhow, `$(window).on('scroll', function() {...`  is how it usually works. If you really want to isolate content from scroll event but want it on the same page, then use an iframe since it's a different window.

Comment: ok, will yyou can use a filter jquery class or id to prevent  use it, in : $(myelemt).parentsUntil("html").add($(window));

Comment: yes  @zer00ne want register window and body too but i want exclude particular child is that possible?

Comment: An iframe has a different window , document, and body yet it exists on same page.

Comment: If you don't want to use an extra page, you can use the iframe attribute [`srcdoc`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/iframe). That'll allow you to use isolated content on the same page.

Comment: @ÁlvaroTouzón how to filter the elements (actually i want to filter with argument (myelement). if myelement is my targeted element(mywrapper) then i want to prevent the binding

Comment: @SasiDhivya I found probably what you're looking for. It was so simple I didn't even think about it at first. See my answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [`.off()`](http://api.jquery.com/off/) method is what you need. Originally I had started answering with an iframe solution and came up with the better solution later. 
Since an iframe's context is different than it's parent, it is not included if you register everything on the parent page.

1. In the [<kbd>**PLUNKER**</kbd>](http://embed.plnkr.co/n2bd2jRWBmBcLg90rZAN/), the first section has an iframe with `srcdoc` and content within. Scroll the iframe and you'll notice that it isn't triggering the scroll counter.
2. Same thing with the second section that has a normal iframe.
3. The third and fourth section have scrolling content.
4. As expected, both trigger the scroll event.
5. Click the <kbd>**IV OFF**</kbd> button which uses the [`.off()`](http://api.jquery.com/off/) method.
6. Now scroll section IV and notice the scroll counter isn't increasing.

`.off()` is what you need. Make sure to use this expression:

> ```
> $('*').on('scroll', function() {....
> ```

That `*` will register everything but iframe content on a page so you don't have to write all of that code you had in your question.

Answer (score 0):

You could jus use the `:not()` CSS selector

```
var element = $(myelemt + ':not(#mywrapper3)').parentsUntil("html").add($(window));    
element.on("scroll", function (e) {
 $("#mywrapper3").html($("#mywrapper3").html() + "scrolling<br>");
}
```

Comment: hi, this is what i need but i cannot able to use id like in code and i want to filter with myelemt (for example if myelemt is my div where i want to prevent)